# Blinking 'cursor' aligns to left in right-aligned text input fields MS Edge

Tags: html, css, input, cursor, alignment

I created a right-aligned html text input field in MS Edge. When first selecting the field, the blinking cursor is left-aligned. It changes to be right-aligned after typing something.

Here is my css:

```
input {
    text-align: right;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    font: 25px/50px 'Segoe UI Light','Helvetica Neue',Calibri,Arial;
    color: #369;
}
```

Is this the usual behavior? How can I make the cursor right-aligned even when the field is empty?

Comment: sorry, the 'cursor' is correctly called a 'caret'

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem on my phone. (My phone currently being the only device that has Edge on it, sorry.) https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/79ajLu4L/ The caret is to the right.